# Joining three junction tables

Tags: mysql, sql, junction-table

my heads hurt from trying to figure this out!

I have three tables
-Players
-Teams
-Games

Three junction tables with two columns.
-player_teams
-teams_games
-player_games

I need to list all Players who are in a Game (eg: Game_id = 111 from variable) that are not assigned a Team(in this game). i call them orphaned players

Basically get Teams that are in the game, get their Players and reverse match against Games_players. or the other way round i suppose.

i tried for two day no luck!

thanks!

/J
p.s after i posted this i got this far but it seems to complex!

```
SELECT * from players
JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT games_players.player_id from games_players
Left JOIN
(Select team_players.player_id p1 from team_players 
inner join (Select * from games_teams where games_teams.game_id = :P1) AS tm1 ON team_players.team_id = tm1.team_id) As f1
On games_players.player_id = f1.p1
where p1 is null) as q1
on players.player_id = q1.player_id
```

Comment: Table definitions, sample input and expected output please. You probably want something like a `NOT EXISTS` query (Your actual database design is problematic as I'm sure you have understood. The `player_games` table probably shouldn't actually exist)

Comment: Well players sign up to play games, pay a fee,  then get assigned a team. they can play many games and be on different team each time. any suggestions? actually think i did i solved it, but not pretty

Comment: I think your main problem here is that you are trying to solve this with joins. Use `[NOT] EXISTS` or `[NOT] IN` instead and the task becomes much easier.

Comment: Then if players *can* be logically assigned to a game without a team, then `team_players` should probably refer instead to `player_games` so that all ream players are actually in that game

Comment: thanks ! i will look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the game is given, you can just look at the players in the game and the players of the teams in the game:

```
select *
from players
where player_id in
(
  select player_id
  from player_games
  where game_id = 111
)
and player_id not in
(
  select pt.player_id
  from player_teams pt
  join teams_games tg using (team_id)
  where tg.game_id = 111
);
```

Comment: WOW wow!!! so ellegant! i have alot learn!   works beautifully!

Comment: @kattouf be careful with `NOT IN` queries, they behave strangely in the presence of nullable columns. You can trivially convert this to a `[NOT] EXISTS` though